# PHP - Function To Find Links In Text

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

I have got a function that converts strings like 'www.example.com' and 'http://example.com' in hyperlinks. It also deals with subdomains e.g. 'http://sub.example.com'.

But it fails with this one - **http://www**.example.com' and outputs the following

```
<a href="http://<a href="http://www.chemica.ru">www.chemica.ru</a>">http://<a href="http://www.chemica.ru">www.chemica.ru</a></a>
```

**Please, can anyone help? The problem is that both 'http://' and 'www.' are together and both have different ways of converting.**

```
function makeLinks($text){ 
 $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text); 
 $text = eregi_replace('(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', '<a href="http://\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
 $text = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})', '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $text); 
 return $text; 
}
```

Comment: FYI, eregi_* functions are deprecated. You should switch to preg_replace at some point in the near future.

Comment: PCRE allows for more advanced regex features than POSIX, as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract http links from a paragraph and store them in a array on php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861324/how-to-extract-http-links-from-a-paragraph-and-store-them-in-a-array-on-php)

Answer (score 4):

just write to your view's page (you dont need any library or helper function) :

```
$text = "Good Site is http://masalahkita.com";
$link = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $text);

echo $link;
```

Comment: This code  works up to PHP7.2.31 but fails from 7.3 onwards ("preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 14"). See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81dd9ff6b356368fa3484c7ea897eebf261d2516

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read [this blog post by Jan Goyvaerts](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/) for some ideas on how to find URLs in text.

To solve your immediate problem, you could add a negative lookbehind to your second regex: `(?<!http://)(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&/=]+)` ensures that `www...` will only be matched if it is not preceded by `http://`.

However, `ereg` functions are deprecated and don't support lookaround, so you'll need to use `preg_replace()`.

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!http:\/\/)(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]+)/i', '<a href="http://\1">\1</a>', $text);
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

For both `'http://'` and `'www.'` **together**, you can do something like [this](http://codepad.org/SwB9Ij1z):

```
$text = "http://www.example.com is a nice site";
$link = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $text);
echo $link;
```

Works for URLs starts with **http://**

Comment: As above in andy's solution - this works up until PHP7.3