# Find links in page and run it through custom function

Tags: php, regex, url

```
function link_it($text)
{
    $text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"$3\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>", $text);  
    $text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((www|ftp)\.[^ \,\"\t\n\r<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"http://$3\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>", $text);  
    $text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+)+)/i", "$1<a href=\"mailto:$2@$3\" target=\"_blank\">$2@$3</a>", $text);  
    return($text);  
}
```

That's the working code.

I'm working on a new function

```
function shorturl2full($url)
{
    echo 'URL IS: ' . $url;
    return "FULLLINK";
}
```

The idea is to take the url and return it back. Later going to work on turning it in to the full url. So like `t.co` will be full url they will see.

```
$text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"$3\" target=\"_blank\">" .  shorturl2full("$3") . "</a>", $text);  
        $text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((www|ftp)\.[^ \,\"\t\n\r<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"http://$3\" target=\"_blank\">" .  shorturl2full("$3") . "</a>", $text);  
        $text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+)+)/i", "$1<a href=\"mailto:$2@$3\" target=\"_blank\">$2@$3</a>", $text);  
        return($text);  
}
```

Is my bad try at it.

So if you click the link it should use the original but the one you see should be the output of `shorturl2full`

So like `<a href="t.co">FULLLINK</a>`

I want to attempt to write the `shorturl2full` function on my own and i think i have a very great idea on how to do it. The problem is in the `link_it` function... It needs to pass the url to the `shorturl2full` function and display what ever it returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use preg_replace_callback instead of preg_replace http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

```
function link_it($text)
{
    $text= preg_replace_callback("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t<]*)/is",  'shorturl2full', $text);  
    $text= preg_replace_callback("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((www|ftp)\.[^ \,\"\t\n\r<]*)/is",  'shorturl2full', $text);  
    $text= preg_replace_callback("/(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+)+)/i",  'shorturl2full', $text);  
    return($text);  
}

function shorturl2full($url)
{
    $fullLink = 'FULLLINK';
    // $url[0] is the complete match
    //... you code to find the full link
    return '<a href="' . $url[0] . '">' . $fullLink . '</a>';
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861324/how-to-extract-http-links-from-a-paragraph-and-store-them-in-a-array-on-php/6861706#6861706) I have shown a function called `make_clickable` which has an optional callback parameter which get's applied to each URI if set:

```
make_clickable($text, 'shorturl2full');
```

Maybe it's helpful or gives some ideas at least.