# PHP: Regexp to change urls

Tags: php, regex, url, replace, bbcode

I'm looking for nice regexp which could change me string from:

```
text text website.tld text text anotherwebsite.tld/longeraddress text http://maybeanotheradress.tld/file.ext
```

into bbcodes

```
text text [url=website.tld]LINK[/url] text text [url=anotherwebsite.tld/longeradress]LINK[/url] text text [url=http://maybeanotheradress.tld/file/ext]LINK[/url]
```

Could you please advice?

Comment: How are you going to distinguish text from web-site address?

Comment: First of all I though about splitting strings by delimiters: ":", "-", and a spacebar

Comment: @AdrianK. "hi.com whit me" (example of poorly written phrase). Given your current rules, `hi.com` should be interpreted as an URL. I recommend to force URLs to be prefixed with a protocol.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find links in page and run it through custom function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630419/find-links-in-page-and-run-it-through-custom-function)

Comment: @ArianK: This has been asked numerous times, even today already. Please use the search, there are different approaches how you could do that, in the end it does not depend whether you insert BBCODE or just a HTML A tag.

Comment: @hakre: yeah, I'm sorry - I was typing wrong keywords in search box that's why I decided to make new post. Seems that your link can help me alot!

Comment: @AdrianK: I also added an answer now to show you a common technique to deal with such string "problems", it's not a full solution, just to outline one way you could start to conquer the problem. And mind the false positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I vote for duplicate, a general suggestion: *Divide and Conquer*.

In your input string, all "URLs" do not contain any spaces. So you can divide the string into the parts that do not contain spaces:

```
$chunks = explode(' ', $str);
```

As we know that each part is now potentially a *link* you can create your own function that is able to tell so:

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
function is_text_link($str)
{
    # do whatever you need to do here to tell whether something is
    # a link in your domain or not.

    # for example, taken the links you have in your question:

    $links = array(
        'website.tld', 
        'anotherwebsite.tld/longeraddress', 
        'http://maybeanotheradress.tld/file.ext'
    );

    return in_array($str, $links);
}
```

The `in_array` is just an example, you might be looking for regular expression based pattern matching instead. You can edit it later to fit your needs, I leave this as an exercise.

As you can now say what a link is and what not, the only problem left is how to create a BBCode out of a link, that's a fairly simple string operation:

```
 if (is_link($chunk))
 {
     $chunk = sprintf('[url=%s]LINK[/url]', $chunk);
 }
```

So technically, all problems have been solved and this needs to be put together:

```
function bbcode_links($str)
{
    $chunks = explode(' ', $str);
    foreach ($chunks as &$chunk)
    {
        if (is_text_link($chunk))
        {
             $chunk = sprintf('[url=%s]LINK[/url]', $chunk);
        }              
    }
    return implode(' ', $chunks);
}
```

This already runs with your example string in question ([Demo](http://codepad.org/0g0oVkeK)):

```
$str = 'text text website.tld text text anotherwebsite.tld/longeraddress text http://maybeanotheradress.tld/file.ext';

echo bbcode_links($str);
```

Output:

```
text text [url=website.tld]LINK[/url] text text [url=anotherwebsite.tld/longeraddress]LINK[/url] text [url=http://maybeanotheradress.tld/file.ext]LINK[/url]
```

You then only need to tweak your `is_link` function to fullfill your needs. Have fun!