# Find links in string with PHP. Differ from normal and youtube links

Tags: php, youtube, exp

I have a string that contain links. I want my php to do different things with my links, depending on the url.

Answer:

```
function fixLinks($text)
{       
        $links = array();
        $text = strip_tags($text);    
        $pattern = '!(https?://[^\s]+)!'; 
        if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches)) {
            list(, $links) = ($matches);
        }

        $i = 0;
        $links2 = array();
        foreach($links AS $link) {
            if(strpos($link,'youtube.com') !== false) {
                $search = "!(http://.*youtube\.com.*v=)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})(&.*)?!";
                $youtube = '<a href="youtube.php?id=\\2" class="fancy">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\\2</a>';
                $link2 = preg_replace($search, $youtube, $link);
            } else {
                $link2 = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank"><u>$1</u></a>', $link);
            }
            $links2[$i] = $link2;
            $i++;     
        }
        $text = str_replace($links, $links2, $text);
        $text = nl2br($text);

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: I would try harder and throw even more regular expressions onto it. This normally helps to completely loose anything out of sight :) - This has a callback, so you can first extract all links and then look for youtube: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861324/how-to-extract-http-links-from-a-paragraph-and-store-them-in-a-array-on-php/6861706#6861706 - here for a youtube regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556559/youtube-api-extract-video-id/6556662#6556662

Comment: Well it's just a test of some come i found. I'm open for suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, ditch `eregi`. It's deprecated and will disappear soon.

Then, doing this in just one pass is maybe a stretch too far. I think you'll be better off splitting this into three phases.

**Phase 1** runs a regex search over your input, finding everything that looks like a link, and storing it in a list.

**Phase 2** iterates over the list, checking whether a link goes to youtube (`parse_url` is tremendously useful for this), and putting a suitable replacement into a second list.

**Phase 3**: you now have two lists, one containing the original matches, one containing the desired replacements. Run str_replace over your original text, providing the match list for the search parameter and the replacement list for the replacements.

There are several advantages to this approach:

1. The regular expression for extracting links can be kept relatively simple, since it doesn't have to take special hostnames into account
2. It is easier to debug; you can dump the search and replace arrays prior to phase 3, and see if they contain what you expect
3. Because you perform all replacements in one go, you avoid problems with overlapping matches or replacing a piece of already-replaced text (after all, the replaced text still contains a URL, and you don't want to replace that again)

Comment: Okay I managed to do it :-) Thank you very much. Pls comment on my code for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

[tdammers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894107/find-links-in-string-with-php-differ-from-normal-and-youtube-links/7894241#7894241) is good, but another option is to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback). If you go with that, then the process changes a little:

1. Create a regular expression to match all links, same as his Phase 1
2. In the callback, search for the YouTube video id. This will require running a second `preg_match`, which is (in my opinion) the biggest problem with this technique.
3. Return the replacement string, based on whether or not it's YouTube.

The code would look something like this:

```
function replaceem($matches) {
    $url = $matches[0];
    preg_match('~youtube\.com.*v=([\w\-]{11})~', $url, $matches);
    return isset($matches[0]) ?
        '<a href="youtube.php?id='.$matches[1].'" class="fancy">'.
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$matches[1].'</a>' :
        '<a href="'.$url.'" title="Åben link" alt="Åben link" '.
        'target="_blank">'.$url.'</a>';
}
$text = preg_replace_callback('~(?:f|ht)tps?://[^\s]+~', 'replaceem', $text);
```