# How to linkify URLs in Codeigniter?

Tags: url, preg-replace, codeigniter-2

I'd like to setup a function in Codeigniter that would turn URLs into active links. I found the function below [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762666/php-function-to-find-links-in-text)--it's for PHP generally, but need something similar for Codeigniter. Would like to use it throughout my site for user posts and comments.

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!http:\/\/)(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]+)/i', '<a href="http://\1">\1</a>', $text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using auto_link() which is a function built into codeigniter. So if someone posts a message and you want to linkify any urls, simply use:

```
auto_link($message)
```

I found it buried in the codeigniter documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Make a [helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) and autoload it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put preg_replace command into view your page like this:
$ text = "visit the web http://masalahkita.com to see this work. Web is using CodeIgniter framework and apply this way.";
$ link = preg_replace("/([\w]+://[\w-?&;#~=./\@]+[\w/])/i","$1", $text);
echo $ link;

Answer (score 0):

Consider [URL Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) in CI. There are a couple of functions that assist in working with URLs. Take a look at the `anchor()` function specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `MY_text_helper.php` in `application/helpers`

put the following function in there:

```
function linkify($text){
    return preg_replace('/(?<!http:\/\/)(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]+)/i', '<a href="http://\1">\1</a>', $text);
}
```

Now in your controller:

```
//$content = 'get your content from somewhere'
$this->load->helper('text');
$content = linkify($content);
```