# Replacing links in text with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following RegEx to replace links in the text with clickable links:

```
preg_replace('/(http)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '<a href="\0" target="_blank" class="lgray">\0</a>',$message);
```

I need a new one, that will recognize links starting with www only as well as those with http. Here's a list of the required URL types:

- www.example.com/
- http://example.com/
- http://www.example.com/
- www.example.com
- http://example.com
- http://www.example.com
- https://example.com/
- https://www.example.com/
- https://example.com
- https://www.example.com

I've tried to do it by myself, but I'm not very good in RegEx-s. Will appreciate any help.

Thank you!

**P.S:** *stackoverflow also does not recognize URLs starting with www only.*

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762666/php-function-to-find-links-in-text) if it's the same

Comment: @khaled_webdev - This gets only 2 of them right. It misses 6 of them and it totaly messed up 2 of them. The second and third comment also does not work.

Comment: this [one](http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/markup_urls) unless not with https and need modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Claus Witt's link and modifying it just a little did the job. The preg_replace he gave did not work though. Here's what I did:

```
$regex = "(((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)|(www))";//Scheme
$regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,4})";//Host or IP
$regex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?";//Port
$regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?";//Path
$regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?";//GET Query
$regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?";//Anchor
return str_replace
(
    array('href="','http://http://','http://https://','http:///'),
    array('href="http://','http://','https://','/'),
    preg_replace('/'.$regex.'/i','<a href="\0" target="_blank" class="lgray">\0</a>',$message)
);
```

In the modification I made the **http** or the **www** required, removed some non-necessary checks and extended the domain extension from 3 to 4 characters (.info is a domain too).

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you have made the colon and the two slashes mandatory.

This line should remedy that:

```
preg_replace('/(http|https)?(:)?(\/\/)?((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '<a href="\0" target="_blank" class="lgray">\0</a>',$domains);
```

For a better answer, try looking at [Regular expression pattern to match url with or without http://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427530/regular-expression-pattern-to-match-url-with-or-without-http-www)

Comment: Sorry, but that's definitely not right. Your regex matches all kinds of results that shouldn't work, such as `://www.`

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: These are very basic, and will not account for checking valid TLDs or file extensions. Use at your own risk.**

Assuming you don't need to account for directories or files, to match only those base URLs without subdomains, [you can use the following regex](http://regexr.com?316qo):

```
(?<=^|[\n\s])(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.com\/?(?=$|[\n\s])
```

```
#DESCRIPTION::
#  (?<=^|[\n\s])           Checks to see that what's preceding the URL is the beginning of the string, or a newline, or whitespace.
#  (?:https?:\/\/)?        Matches http(s) if it is there
#  (?:www\.)?              Matches www. if it is there
#  [a-zA-Z0-9-]+           Matches "example" in "example.com" (as well as any other valid URL character; will also match subdomains)
#  \.com\/?                Matches .com(/)
#  (?=$|[\n\s])            Checks to see that what's following the URL is the end of the string, or a newline, or whitespace.
```

---

If you need to also match directories and files, [the end of the regex needs to be modified and added to slightly](http://regexr.com?316ql):

```
(?<=^|[\n\s])(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.com(?:(?:\/[\w]+)+)?(?:\/|\.[\w]+)?(?=$|[\n\s])
```

```
#DESCRIPTION::
#  (?<=^|[\n\s])           Checks to see that what's preceding the URL is the beginning of the string, or a newline, or whitespace.
#  (?:https?:\/\/)?        Matches http(s) if it is there
#  (?:www\.)?              Matches www. if it is there
#  [a-zA-Z0-9-.]+          Matches "example" in "example.com" (as well as any other valid URL character; will also match subdomains)
#  \.com                   Matches .com
#  (?:                     Start of a group
#     (?:\/[\w]+)+         Attempts to find subdirectories by matching /, then word characters
#  )?                      Ends the previous group. This group can be skipped, if there are no subdirectories
#  (?:\/|\.[\w]+)?         Matches a file extension if it is there, or a / if it is there.
#  (?=$|[\n\s])            Checks to see that what's following the URL is the end of the string, or a newline, or whitespace.
```

Comment: And to use these with a regex replace, just wrap the entire URL in a single capture group `( ... )`, and use `\0` in your replace string.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
$pattern = preg_replace("/((https:\/\/|http:\/\/||http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|www.)+([\w\/])+(.com\/|.com))/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>",$url);
```

Comment: Not only does this make the `http(s)...` section required, but it also allows for bogus protocol sections of a url, like this: `https://www.http://abc.com`